# I have some problems with scraping second element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I’m not a programmer by the way, but in my spare time I try to have a little fun.
I am currently trying to scrape some data from the website and have half success.

I want to scrape two data from an image in description marked with red letters 1 and 2. My only requirement is that xpath must contain "PinnacleSport" text, so as not to confuse it with many others.

Here is the code that works for my first data:

```
 pinnacle_opening_home = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//th[b[contains(text (), 'PinnacleSports')]]/following-sibling::td[2]").text
```

It's not very clear to me how to do something similar for other data, so the xpath containing the text "PinnacleSport".

It is completely clear to me that I can use folowing:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//html/body/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[4]/table /tbody/tr[21]/td[2]").text
```

... but the pages are changeable and this would make a mistake for me in some situations.

Can someone give me some instructions on what to try?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5heqJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, or some variation, and see if it works:

```
//tr[th[b[contains(text (), 'PinnacleSports')]]]/following-sibling::tr//td[2]
```